# set attribute value dynamically from from event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set the value of an attribute to show 'x' amount of stars but need to run an event to my database to get the average and use that number?

here is this HTML with the 'data-rateit-value' attribute id like to modify dynamically.

```
<div id="randomtest" data-productid="randomtest" class="rateit" data-rateit-value=""></div>
```

i tried this just to modify it without an event to query the database and it didnt set it?
so need some advise before i go on to including the event.

```
$('#randomtest').attr( 'data-rateit-value','4');
```

but once im able to i will be able to set it dynamically like i have made a basic demo of below?
if not some further guidance would be much appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'currentvalue.php',
    data: { id: productID, value: value },
    type: 'POST',

    success: setCurrentValue
});

function setCurrentValue(data) {
    $('#randomtest').attr( 'data-rateit-value'.append(data));
}
```

thanks for any help

**EDIT**
i changed the query and results to this and it alerts with the integer but still doesn't append to the attribute

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'currentstars.php', //your server side script
    data: { id: productID, value: value }, //our data
    type: 'POST',

    success: function(results) { 
    alert(results);
    $('.rateit').attr( 'data-rateit-value'.append(results))
    }
});
```

i don't know if this helps with anyone trying to work out why it's not working?

Comment: What doesn't work about what you have above? Looks good to me

Comment: once the 'data-rateit-value' attribute is given a value that value is expressed in highlighted stars but it doesn't change the amount of stars that are highlighted like expected?

Comment: ".attr( 'data-rateit-value'.append(data));" looks good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!!

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'currentstars.php',
    data: { id: productID, value: value },
    type: 'POST',

    success: function(results) { 
    $('.rateit').rateit('value', (results));
    }
});
```

with that query and function i'm able to update to the average rating when both the page is loaded and when a rating is selected!!!

what a nightmare that was lol :)

Answer (score 1):

First I would say you should check that you are getting back what you expect from the server:

```
function setCurrentValue(data) {
    console.log(data);
    ...
}
```

What is the structure of `data`?

I'm not sure what you want to happen with the setCurrentValue function, you have some syntax errors in the line `$('#randomtest').attr( 'data-rateit-value'.append(data));`.
`attr` can be called like `attr(attribute, value)` so maybe `$('#randomtest').attr( 'data-rateit-value', data);` is closer to what you need

Comment: i am getting what i expect back from the server i already have a different function the gives the results in a div that i made to test it? which a is a integer rounded to .5

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use .append on attributes,which i don't think is the right way.
Try this-

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'currentvalue.php',
    data: { id: productID, value: value },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(){setCurrentValue(data);}
 });

function setCurrentValue(data) {
    $('#randomtest').attr( 'data-rateit-value',data);
    //Or $('#randomtest').data( 'rateit-value',data);
}
```

Comment: neither worked? i've been at this a while and im at a loss as to why its not working as expected?

Comment: did u try console.log(data) or alert(data) inside setCurrentValue() ?

Comment: i can alert it and i just inspected it and it seems to be an issue with the js plugin im looking into it